# UITableView static cell's number of row is changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I make one UITableView Controller had static cell. And I set number of rows 3 in Storyboard. But rows does not set 3, just be made more and more like this screen shot. I don't touch any programatic code. Did I have to make it programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the normal behavior of a UITableView.  Even though you only have 3 rows, the view itself extends to the bottom, and it shows where the cells would be if you had data in them.  To fix, do one of two things:  customize the UITableView so the dividing line between cells is invisible [UIColor clearColor], or change the size of the UITableView's height depending on how many cells you have.

Comment: Sorry, don't think that disabling cells' divider or increase cells' height is a good idea :-) See my answer.

Comment: @Sasha, I didn't suggest changing the cells' height, but the table's height itself.  It appears that the original poster's intent was to limit the appearance of cells to only the number of actual rows, so it depends on whether he wants the table at the full size, with no separator lines below the third or he wants to shrink the actual size of the table to the cell height * number or rows.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem on the story board.

1. Create one more cell. **if you want 3cells, then make 4cells.**
2. Make whatever you want on cell. put the `UIButton` or `UILabel` any way. But except 4th cell.
3. Expend your 4th cell's height, to the bottom.
4. And finally, **check hidden in attributes inspector.** It makes 4th cell hidden.

That's it!
And I add one image file. I hope it help your work. Thanks.

[image: How to make 3cells and fake cell]

Comment: If you want to only disappear the separator, then check the custom cell and input left value huge value(like 320)

Answer (score 1):

If you add a footerView to the UITableView then it will not extend all the way to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to set footer's frame to nil:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    /*........*/
    tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular View Controller and insert a TableView of the required table height.

Then if you really want to you can do stuff with the cell height and label sizes.